# Issue with I2S transmitter - Send constant data

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I have a self made I2S transmitter which receives data over AXI, store them in a FIFO and transmit them. The module should use two switching FIFO to receive data from AXI and transmit over I2S simultaneously.

The problem is that the design doesn´t work on the real hardware and is sending the same data all the time.

[image]

So I simulate the design and the normal simulation looks pretty good.

[image]

But when I run a Post-Synthesis Timing Simulation the output looks different and the output data are constant (like in the real hardware).

[image]

It seems that the signal `ReadCounter` doesn´t increase anymore and stucks at `2`. So the state machine doesn´t change his current state and so the transmitter send the same data all the time, because the data in the FIFO aren´t updated anymore. But I don´t understand why this behavior occur.

Vivado doesn´t output any warnings during the synthesis of the I2S core (the only warning is the missing `TLAST` but this signal is unneccessary atm).

**I2S.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity I2S is
    Generic ( WIDTH  : INTEGER := 16;                                       -- Data width per channel
              RATIO  : INTEGER := 256;                                      -- MCLK / L/R clock split ratio
              FIFO_WIDTH    : INTEGER := 8                                  -- FIFO depth in samples
              );
    Port (  ACLK     : in STD_LOGIC;                                        -- Logic clock
            ARESETn  : in STD_LOGIC;                                        -- Reset (active low)

            -- AXI4 Stream interface
            TDATA    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(((WIDTH * 2) - 1) downto 0);     -- The primary payload that is used to provide the data
            TREADY   : out STD_LOGIC;                                       -- Indicates that the slave can accept a transfer in the
                                                                            -- current cycle
            TVALID   : in STD_LOGIC;                                        -- Indicates that the master is driving a valid transfer
            TLAST    : in STD_LOGIC;                                        -- Indicates the boundary of a packet

            -- I2S interface
            MCLK     : in STD_LOGIC;                                        -- Master audio clock. Must be an integer ration of the
                                                                            -- L/R clock signal
            LRCLK    : out STD_LOGIC;                                       -- L/R clock for the I2S protocol
            SCLK     : out STD_LOGIC;                                       -- I2S clock signal
            SD       : out STD_LOGIC                                        -- I2S data signal
            );
end I2S;

architecture I2S_Arch of I2S is

    type FIFO_STATE_t is (Reset, WaitForValid, ACKData, Full_FIFO_0, Full_FIFO_1);
    type I2S_STATE_t is (Reset, WaitForFIFO, WaitForSync, LoadData, StartTransmission);
    type MEMORY_t is array(0 to (FIFO_WIDTH - 1)) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(((2 * WIDTH) - 1) downto 0);

    signal FIFOState    : FIFO_STATE_t := Reset;
    signal I2SState     : I2S_STATE_t := Reset;
    signal FIFO_0       : MEMORY_t := (others => (others => '0')); 
    signal FIFO_1       : MEMORY_t := (others => (others => '0')); 

    signal MCLK_Cnt     : INTEGER := 0;
    signal BitCounter   : INTEGER := 0;
    signal BytesInFIFO_0: INTEGER := 0;
    signal BytesInFIFO_1: INTEGER := 0;
    signal ReadCounter  : INTEGER := 0;

    signal TREADY_Int       : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal AudioClock       : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal FIFO_0_Full      : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal FIFO_1_Full      : STD_LOGIC := '0';

    signal AudioData    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(((2 * WIDTH) - 1) downto 0) := (others => '0');

    component I2S_Transmitter is
        Generic ( WIDTH  : INTEGER := 24
                  );
        Port (  CLK      : in STD_LOGIC;
                RESETn   : in STD_LOGIC;
                Data     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(((2 * WIDTH) - 1) downto 0);
                LRCLK    : out STD_LOGIC;
                SCLK     : out STD_LOGIC;
                SD       : out STD_LOGIC;
                BitCounter : out INTEGER
                );
    end component;

begin

    Transmitter : I2S_Transmitter generic map ( WIDTH => WIDTH 
                                                )
                                  port map ( CLK => AudioClock,
                                             RESETn => ARESETn,
                                             Data => AudioData,
                                             LRCLK => LRCLK,
                                             SCLK => SCLK,
                                             SD => SD,
                                             BitCounter => BitCounter
                                             );

    -- I2S clock generation
    process(MCLK)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(MCLK)) then
            if(ARESETn = '0') then
               MCLK_Cnt <= 0;
            else
                if(MCLK_Cnt = ((RATIO / (4 * WIDTH)) - 1)) then
                    MCLK_Cnt <= 0;
                    AudioClock <= not AudioClock;
                else
                    MCLK_Cnt <= MCLK_Cnt + 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(ACLK)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(ACLK)) then
            case I2SState is
                when Reset =>
                    FIFO_1 <= (others => (others => '0')); 
                    AudioData <= (others => '0');
                    BytesInFIFO_1 <= 0;
                    FIFO_1_Full <= '0';

                    if      ARESETN = '1' then I2SState <= WaitForFIFO;
                    end if;

                when WaitForFIFO =>
                    if      FIFO_0_Full = '1' then  FIFO_1 <= FIFO_0;
                                                    FIFO_1_Full <= '1';
                                                    I2SState <= WaitForSync;
                                                    BytesInFIFO_1 <= BytesInFIFO_0;
                    end if;

                when WaitForSync =>
                    if      (BitCounter = ((2 * WIDTH) - 1)) then   I2SState <= LoadData;
                    end if;

                when LoadData =>
                    AudioData <= FIFO_1(ReadCounter);

                    if      ReadCounter < BytesInFIFO_1 then    ReadCounter <= ReadCounter + 1;
                    else    ReadCounter <= 0;
                            FIFO_1_Full <= '0';
                    end if;

                    I2SState <= StartTransmission;

                when StartTransmission =>
                    if      BitCounter = 0 then 
                        if      FIFO_1_Full = '1' then    I2SState <= WaitForSync;
                        else    I2SState <= WaitForFIFO;
                        end if;
                    else    I2SState <= StartTransmission;
                    end if;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(ACLK)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(ACLK)) then
            case FIFOState is
                when Reset =>
                    FIFO_0 <= (others => (others => '0')); 
                    TREADY_Int <= '0';
                    FIFO_0_Full <= '0';
                    BytesInFIFO_0 <= 0;

                    if      ARESETN = '1' then FIFOState <= WaitForValid;
                    end if;

                when WaitForValid =>
                    FIFO_0_Full <= '0';
                    if      TVALID = '1' then FIFOState <= ACKData;
                                              TREADY_Int <= '1';
                    elsif   TVALID = '0' then FIFOState <= WaitForValid;
                                              TREADY_Int <= '0';
                    end if;       

                when ACKData =>
                    TREADY_Int <= '0';
                    FIFO_0(BytesInFIFO_0) <= TDATA;

                    if      BytesInFIFO_0 < (FIFO_WIDTH - 1) then   BytesInFIFO_0 <= BytesInFIFO_0 + 1;
                                                                    FIFOState <= WaitForValid;
                    else    FIFO_0_Full <= '1';

                            if      FIFO_1_Full = '0' then  FIFOState <= Full_FIFO_0;
                            else    FIFOState <= Full_FIFO_1;
                            end if;
                    end if;

                when Full_FIFO_0 =>
                    if      FIFO_1_Full = '1' then  FIFOState <= WaitForValid;
                                                    BytesInFIFO_0 <= 0;
                    end if;

                when Full_FIFO_1 =>
                    if      FIFO_1_Full = '1' then  FIFOState <= Full_FIFO_1;
                    elsif   FIFO_0_Full = '1' then  FIFOState <= Full_FIFO_0;
                    end if;

            end case;
        end if;
    end process;

    TREADY <= TREADY_Int;
end I2S_Arch;
```

**I2S_Transmitter.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity I2S_Transmitter is
    Generic ( WIDTH  : INTEGER := 16                                            -- Data width per channel
              );
    Port (  CLK      : in STD_LOGIC;                                            -- Input clock for the module
            RESETn   : in STD_LOGIC;                                            -- Reset (active low)
            Data     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(((2 * WIDTH) - 1) downto 0);         -- Input data for both channel
            LRCLK    : out STD_LOGIC;                                           -- L/R clock output signal
            SCLK     : out STD_LOGIC;                                           -- I2S output clock signal
            SD       : out STD_LOGIC;                                           -- I2S output data
            BitCounter : out INTEGER                                            -- Bit counter output signal
            );
end I2S_Transmitter;

architecture I2S_Transmitter_Arch of I2S_Transmitter is

    signal SD_Int           : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal LRCLK_Int        : STD_LOGIC := '1';
    signal ShiftReg         : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(((2 * WIDTH) - 1) downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal BitCounter_Int   : INTEGER := 0;

begin

    process(CLK)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(CLK)) then
            if(RESETn = '0') then
                LRCLK_Int <= '1';
                BitCounter_Int <= 0;
                ShiftReg <= (others => '0');
                SD_Int <= '0';
            else
                if(BitCounter_Int < ((2 * WIDTH) - 1)) then
                    BitCounter_Int <= BitCounter_Int + 1;
                else
                    BitCounter_Int <= 0;
                end if;

                -- L/R logic
                if(BitCounter_Int < WIDTH) then
                    LRCLK_Int <= '0';
                else
                    LRCLK_Int <= '1';
                end if;

                -- Handle the shift register
                if(BitCounter_Int = 0) then
                    ShiftReg <= Data;
                else
                    ShiftReg <= ShiftReg(((2 * WIDTH) - 2) downto 0) & "0";
                end if;

                SD_Int <= ShiftReg((2 * WIDTH) - 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    BitCounter <= BitCounter_Int;
    SD <= SD_Int;
    LRCLK <= LRCLK_Int;
    SCLK <= CLK and RESETn;
end I2S_Transmitter_Arch;
```

**Update from 11.08.2019:**

I have applied some of the changes from @Uros Maric (see code above). The current waveform looks like this

[image]

Zoomed in at 1950 us:

[image]

Zoomed in at 1965 us:

[image]

You can also download the [Simulation database file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/carli1t6n1okz6g/Testbench_behav.wdb?dl=0)(Testbench_behav.wdb) or the [whole](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5ui62qpe3fykvx3/AAAST6pC1nGQBtC9ha-t9cXja?dl=0) project from my Dropbox.

It seems that the I2S state machine switches to a state with the ID 6, but I only have 5 states (ID 0 to 4). That looks a little bit weird...

Comment: You have the post-synthesis simulation running. That is your best tool for debugging the problem. Don't try to debug your source code by inspection.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't use `AudioClock` as a clock for your component `Transmitter : I2S_Transmitter` instead use `MCLK` as the clock and `AudioClock` as a enable when you want action to take place. The way you did it is that you generated a new signal which will pretend that it is a clock signal, but it isn't. Look it up on the net to see how to generate a real clock, but hear I would use `MCLK` and a enable signal inside your component. You don't want to cross a lot of clock domains, believe me.
2. Your sensitivity lists of the processes are overpopulated. If the first thing you check is the edge of a clock than that means you are making a registered signal and you don't need to know the values of any other signal. The only time when you put another signal in there, besides the clock, is when you have an asynchronous reset, then you put it in the sensitivity list, but here you used a synchronous reset, so you only need the clock. When you make a combinational process then you put all the signals in.
3. `elsif   ARESETN = '0' then I2SState <= Reset;` You don't need this line, it is implied because you made a register. You also wouldn't put  `else I2SState <= Reset;` You are just making the design more unreadable and may use more resources. If it were a non-registered process than you should use else and not elsif to close your if statement.
4. Look how to make a two-process FSM, it will help you a lot, it saved my ass more than once.
5. Why use:

   if (BitCounter < ((2 * WIDTH) - 1)) then I2SState <= WaitForSync;
   else I2SState <= LoadData;
   end if;

   And not:

   if (BitCounter >= ((2 * WIDTH) - 1)) then I2SState <= LoadData;
   end if;

   That is it for now. I would also maybe change the FIFO writing FSM concerning the `TVALID` and `TREADY` signals, so as to not lose a clock period in the handshake but the upper 5 points are more urgent for you. When you implement the new design send us the updated version and somebody will check if there is anything else that needs to improve and check the logic of the design.

Best of luck in the endeavors

Comment: Thank you for your in detail analysis. I will change the code according to your tips. But at least I will ignore the first point because I think that this point needs some more rework of the transmitter and currently the transmitter works even in hardware (I tested it with some hardcoded values). But I keep this in mind for a next version - or I do it until next week maybe... I have to see... :)
Unfortunately, your tips don´t solve the problem and I´m struggling with the debugging in the simulation of the implemented design because I don´t do this before

Comment: Small update, because the limit for the text is reached at my first comment...
The simulation gives another result now, but there are a few wrong states inside of the simulation result which is shown as additional `TREADY` signals. I will update the screenshots too...

Comment: Add in the simulation the value of your state machines. There is a posibility that you are stuck in this step because you can't get out of it and change states, you'll aways stay in Full_FIFO_1 state:
`    when  => Full_FIFO_1
     if      FIFO_1_Full = '1' then  FIFOState <= Full_FIFO_1;
     elsif   FIFO_0_Full = '1' then  FIFOState <= Full_FIFO_0;
     end if;`

Comment: The Simulation already contains the states of the state machines, but the synthesis replace them by values and now I don´t have the state names in the simulation, just numbers from 0 to 7. Do you have an idea how to add the names?

Comment: I don't see I2S state FSM in the post-synth and i think that it is the problem. And could you zoom in on the 190 us mark? Make it be from 180 us to 300 us soo that we can see what changes in that time period and why your system stops working properly. The numbers of the states are equal to their respective positions when you constructed the states, so the 0 value is equal to Reset state, 1 to the WaitForXXX state and soo on.

Comment: I´ve applied some of your changes and now the design runs pretty well in the post-implementation timing simulation. But I write `if (BitCounter = ((2 * WIDTH) - 1)) then I2SState <= LoadData; end if;` and not `if (BitCounter >= ((2 * WIDTH) - 1)) then I2SState <= LoadData; end if;`, because your solution doesn´t work. At least the design will enter the state from above now at ~1800 µs. I´ve updated my post.